# Word VBA shape forecolor wdThemeColorAccent2 shows as ThemeColor 1 in the menu

Tags: vba, ms-word, themes, shapes

I wrote some macro code in Word (Office 365) to set the color of a shape outline to one of the theme colors. The code for doing that to a shape looks like this:

```
shape.line.foreColor.ObjectThemeColor = wdThemeColorAccent2
```

By assigning a 'wdXX' color to the `ObjectThemeColor` field, the color of the line around the shape will automatically change when the document ColorTheme is changed.

My problem (or the first weirdness) is that when I assign Accent2 with the code above and then do: select the shape, Menu, Format, Shape Outline, and hover over the color box with a red outline (which marks the active line color), the tooltip says "Turquoise, Accent 1" not "Accent 2."

I would have expected the `wdThemeColorAccent2` color to be called `Accent 2` in the tooltip, but it is not.

The second problem is that there is apparently no way for me to assign the last color shown in the menu using macro code. Because of the offset (Accent 2 in code = Accent 1 in the menu), I would need to use `wdThemeColorAccent7` in code to assign the last color shown in the menu (labeled Accent 6 in the tooltip).

I'm wondering if this is a bug in Word (it sure looks like it to me), or if I am doing something wrong. To reproduce the situation, I created a simple empty rectangle, selected it, and ran the line of code above to change the outline color of the shape. Here's a little subroutine that illustrates the problem (select your shape before running the subroutine).

```
Sub TestAccent()
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = selection.ShapeRange(1)
shp.line.foreColor.ObjectThemeColor = wdThemeColorAccent4
shp.line.Weight = 0.5
shp.line.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the colors in the "theme scale" (see image below) don't correspond to the names of the `WdThemeColorIndex`, but rather to the underlying numerical value. If you look in the VBA Editor's Object Browser (F2), and search `wdThemeColorAccent` you'll get the full list. Click on a member in the list and at the bottom you'll see the numerical value.

The value 0 is assigned to MainDark1 and isn't recognized by VBA. Values 1, 2 and 3  are assigned to MainLight1, MainDark2 and MainLight2 which are black, white and the first entry in the image (These colors repeat in the last four enumerations for background and text). Values 4 (`wdThemeColorAccent4`) through 9 (`wdThemeColorAccent6`) correspond to the remainder of the colors in the image below. (Note: more discussion after image!)

[image]

So, no, I don't think it's a bug, just your expectations don't match what the developers were thinking when they assigned the numerical enumeration to the enumeration names. Or maybe the people who designed the color schemes changed their minds after the VBA code was locked down... And I imagine the names you see in the tooltips are another step removed from the VBA. You might find the information in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc964302%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) helpful.

If you use the values, rather than the names, things could be less confusing. Or, define your own Enum:

```
Public Enum ColorSchemeAccents
    Accent1 = 3
    Accent2 = 4
    Accent3 = 5
    Accent4 = 6
    Accent5 = 7
    Accent6 = 8
    Accent7 = 9
    Accent8 = 10
End Enum

Sub TestAccent()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    shp.Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = ColorSchemeAccents.Accent8
    shp.Fill.ForeColor = RGB(250, 250, 250)
    shp.Line.Weight = 2
    shp.Line.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I went through the exploration of Text1, Background 1, etc. I could be wrong, but it still seems impossible for me to assign the last color in the menu. If I assign `wdThemeColorAccent6` I actually get the 5th accent color, not the 6th. And since `wdThemeColorAccent7` is undefined, it seems like a bug to me. I probably should not have to resort to making my own enums in order to assign colors because VBA has its own enum ranges wrong (off by 1). For now, I have been compensating by adding +1 to the assigned accents.

Comment: I had no trouble assigning any of the colors visible in the color scheme I show. And no trouble assigning any of the possible 15. The only one that didn't work is Enum val 0, but that's covered by the ones at the end.

Comment: It's possible to assign all the colors, but not by using only the `wdThemeColorAccentN` constants defined by VBA. To assign that last color, you need to write your own code (as you kindly showed) because the VBA `wdThemeColorAccent` constants that show up in Intellisense are off by one, which is why I think it's a bug. No problem; I doubt it affects many people.

Comment: I just read your answer again, and it saved the day. Thank you again for your amazing help. I found that using C# I had to set the enum Accent1 = 5 to get the colors right in Word.

Answer (score 0):

Although the ColorFormat object's .ObjectThemeColor is defined as a wdThemeColorIndex in fact the value depends on context.

If it is a Word object - such as text, then you should use the wdThemeColorIndex constants, but if it is an Office object - such as shape, then you have to use the msoThemeColorIndex constants.  These are weirdly NOT the same - mostly the mso constants are one more than the wd constants, but not for the Background1&2 and Text1&2 cases - Text1&2 are the same in both cases, but for Background1&2 mso is two more than wd.
A side effect of this is that it appears impossible in VBA to set the Background2 colour, as its mso value is 16 and so out-of-range BUT if you use the native GUI to set it, it can be set to 16!

Looks really poor design/implementation that needs cleaning up!

Comment: Thank you for your information! It explains the offset problem and makes the point that Word objects and Office objects are different things. How strange. I wonder if the same offsets and things apply to PowerPoint shapes (PPT objects?) and Office objects. I'll have to check the next time I'm trying to set colors. It's always hit and miss setting colors; I remember the strangeness while trying to set colors in PPT.